# run as testNG is missing

Tags: eclipse, testng

The option `runAs->TestNG` on xml file is missing somehow on my eclipse,
I tried to install the eclipse from scratch and now I have Version: `2018-12 (4.10.0)`.

Also I have latest JDK and JRE testNG is installed as far as I see and when I want to install them again I have a problem.

[image: installation details]
[image: problem]

All the threads that i saw till now nothing helped me and i tried all the solution as i wrote maybe you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the TestNG plugin and Eclipse 2018-12 (https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/408). You can use the current beta version from https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse.

If the picture above of your installed software is the current state of your Eclipse 2018-12 setup, it cannot be a clean install. The version 6.14.x of the TestNG plugin is not compatible with 2018-12. It is not possible to install the plugin with Eclipse. Either the existing Eclipse directories are reused or the plugin directories have been added manually. It is important to remove them. After that, it should be possible to install the version 7 beta of the TestNG plugin.

It should look like this:
[image: installed software]

With this setup, you will get your context menu entry for TestNG:
[image: run as TestNG]

Comment: did that, but now all project is locked and when i choose the project i get nullpointerexception

Comment: ![image](https://i.imgur.com/EaW7g84.jpg)
also i did clean..and nothing

Comment: Did you really install Eclipse 2018-12 from scratch? Does TestNg beta run if you setup a new workspace?

Comment: i am using the same workspace and i installed from scratch

Comment: the option to Run As on the main project was with the TestNG, the missing one was only on an XML that i made seperatly to these project, so i found that the solution was to create the same XML again, and it worked, i think that these is different from what you aim cause i have the TestNG as context menu but not on specific XML

Answer (score 0):

the only solution i founded till now is that i need to install eclipse from scratch and convert the same project again to TestNG and to copy the old XML to the new one, if its the latest eclipse than to download the beta version of TestNG